# Convert Wordpress.com embed links to normal embeds

Tags: import, embed

I've given the task of moving several well established blogs from wordpress.com into an independent hosting using Wordpress. Wordpress.com uses a special parser for taking stuff like this:

```
[youtube=http://youtu.be/JN3n34dS]
```

and converting this to a YouTube embed (for example, this happens with other links too, such as Google Maps, etc).

Is there a systematic way to convert all those links to normal embeds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use phpMyAdmin to do a search&replace on the wordpress database for the old youtube embed string and then replace with the new one. Should be possible since the syntax is similar enough.

**edit:** to add [from this other stackexchange question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8237/embeddables-and-moving-from-wordpress-com-to-self-host):

[Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) is a good plugin to be able to search and replace with Grep through all posts and pages. With that, you can change your shortcodes to the default Embeds « WordPress Codex that self-hosted Wordpress uses, which in its simplest form is just the URL.

Or use [WordPress › Viper's Video Quicktags « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/vipers-video-quicktags/) and search/replace to convert to that form of shortcode.

Comment: are there any plugins that does this conversion for me? is there a list of all the embeds possible in wordpress.com (e.g. there are also google maps embeds)

Comment: added some info above

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways that I can think of

1. Find a plugin that is compatible with that shortcode format
2. Write your own plugin that uses the existing shortcode format from WordPress.com (which I don't think the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) even allows)
3. Strip out the short code and leave the URL. WordPress will handle the embedding automatically: http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds